# How to get logs for Application Error on Heroku

Tags: node.js, logging, heroku, error-logging

I have been trying to redeploy my app hosted on Heroku.

On every redeploy i was getting "Your app was successfully deployed."

But on opening the page i was getting:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.
Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

On opening the logs under the 'Activity' tag gave me logs but it had nothing about what went wrong.

How would one get to know whats causing application error.

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: .. If you are using express, you might want to `console.log` the stack trace like this: https://github.com/TheIronDeveloper/pokemon-wondertrade-analytics/blob/bdbf5ac17a9450546f693365c20f67f785285d1b/index.js#L85-L88

Comment: Yes using expressjs. I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could get the logs for Heroku easily from heroku shell. To get 'heroku shell' on you computer, install heroku toolbelt.

One installed, from 'cmd' login to heroku:

```
heroku login
```

Then you could get the logs:

```
heroku logs --app APPNAME
```

This works irrespective of whether you use git, github or dropbox.